# How to compare two 24 hour time

Tags: php

I have two 24-hour time values and want to compare them using PHP.

I have tried the following:

```
$time="00:05:00"; //5 minutes

if($time1<='00:03:00')
{
 //do some work
}
else
{
 //do something
}
```

Is this the correct way to compare 2 time values using PHP?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use the built-in function [strtotime()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$time="00:05:00"; //5 minutes
if(strtotime($time)<=strtotime('00:03:00')) {
 //do some work
} else {
 //do something
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes, that is correct. You don't need to convert to an integer because 24-hour format is such that the string value is in the exact same order as the numeric.

Comment: Oh really? Such as what, exactly?

Comment: "24:00:00" > "00:00:00", is it not?

Comment: "24:00:00" means "+1 day" in my books. Not that I'd ever use it, I always have the date value in my comparisons.

Answer (score 4):

You could use, php's [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)